# Excel tab-delimited differences between Windows and Mac

Tags: excel, macos

I have an excel file that is used to generate input files for scientific equipment where users fill in their samples and it generates a file the equipment can read. However, I've noticed that if a *Windows* Excel saves the tab-delimited file the machine (which is on Windows) works fine, but if the file is saved from Excel on *Mac*, it doesn't work and throws errors saying "expecting <EOF>".

When I look at the *Windows* file in Notepad++ there's a CRLF at the end of the file and it's missing on the file made on Mac. Is there any way to have that CRLF show up on Mac-saved tab-delimited files, either through Excel itself or add it after it's saved? I've seen to try "Windows Formatted Text" as a format when saving, but it isn't there.

[Windows File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQZ2k.jpg)

[Mac File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS2f5.jpg)

I've also seen the same difference with the CRLF on csv between Windows and Mac.

Comment: Many formats of csv - worth checking out.

Comment: Same thing with csvs - files saved on Mac lack the CR+LF at the end of the file.

Comment: I use a program to save csv on my mac to match the format I need like csv utf-8 and you can specify CR+LF as needed.